# Android app with Oracle MAF, build.xml not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oracle, oracle-maf

I'm currently developing an Android (API 21) app on Eclipse OEPE (Mars) using a 64-bit Win7. The SDK was downloaded and installed by Android Studio (with all the platform-tools and build-tools). I have had no trouble writing the app, but as soon as I try to debug it as described [here (Step 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_oepe_maf_app/tut_oepe_maf_app.html), I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
{WorkspacePath}\HelloWorld\.main.android.1\bin\build.xml:3: The following error occurred while executing this line:
{WorkspacePath}\HelloWorld\.main.android.1\bin\build-set-globals.xml:67: Cannot find C:\AndroidSdk\tools\ant\build.xml imported from {WorkspacePath}\HelloWorld\.main.android.1\bin\build-set-globals.xml

Total time: 895 milliseconds
```

(I'm the one who replaced the path to the workspace with {WorkspacePath}).
I have no idea what's going on and couldn't find anything on internet; any suggestion?

EDIT: I forgot to mention it, but the thing that is bothering me the most is that there's no "ant" folder in {SDKPath}/tools

Comment: Have you looked in your preferences to make sure the path to your SDK directory is correct?

Comment: @Todd yes, i have double checked right now and the path is correct both in the Preferences menu and in the error (C:/AndroidSdk)

Comment: Android Studio by default uses Gradle rather than ant, ant is not in the SDK by as standard. Maybe download ant and put it in the SDK location needed or try use [Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html)

Comment: @Todd I've just tried that, and i still get the same error.